# C++ | Draw in a window with the mouse

Tags: c++, qt, drawing

I'm working with neural nets for a simplehandwritten digit recognition. I've already done this in a little Android app with an accuracy of 80%. But now my net is growing and getting more complex and importing the net of my neural net trainer isn't funny. The teacher has an option for generate C-Code of your net which you can implement in your System. Thats why I changed to C++(I've done some work with C++ years ago).

Now I have to write a programm to draw on a screen with the mouse and convert this to a Bitmap or something else.
I have tried to use Qt but is this the best way to dead with this problem or is this overpowered. I hope you can help me.

Comment: You can do almost everything with Qt. The problem is that you question is too general. Start programming and post you code with question when you get some troubles!

Comment: Well, Qt is a 2+ gigabyte framework, if you are going to use it only for drawing - it does seem like an overkill. But it is a fairly complete application development framework, so if you plan on actually learning it and using it - then why not. What you ask in your question is trivial to do with Qt.